# Create edge loop with C select

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I have a lot of vertices forming lines.
From these vertices I want to create several edge loops.
I am now selecting them separately by clicking on them whilst holding shift and then pressing J to create the edge loop.

Because its faster I would like to be able to select the vertices by pressing C and then holding the mouse button and pan over them. But for some reason it does not create an edgeloop when I press J with this method.

Does somebody have a solution for this?
[image]

Comment: An "Edge Loop" is created by pressing CTRL + "R". I'm not sure that is what you are looking for though. Maybe "edit" your question with more information. Adding a screen grab would help too.

Comment: @Dontwalk if you type **edit** between brackets [ ] , the page automatically generates a link to [edit] the question. Here is also an image that shows the users what to look for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% positive I understood your question correctly, but here goes:

When you select vertices in a specific order by clicking each vertex individually, then Blender uses that order to join the vertices with edges.

When you use brush selection by pressing C then Blender does not get an order.
So now, when you try to join the vertices by pressing J, an error popup is displayed that says: **"Invalid selection order"**

To work around that you can simply press F instead of J to make a face of the selected verices and then you delete the face afterwards, so you end up with just the edges.

Here's a gif showing the whole thing:
[image: Different approah using F instead of J]

Comment: This is a great tip. It's very frustrating that  verts selected with 'C' don't remember the order they were selected in.

Comment: This is indeed a good work around, thank you. The only problem is that my verticis are forming a line. So when I create a face a very weird shape shows up with not one coresponding line. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @janne looking at the screenshot you provided in your edit, I'd actually say do a retopo or look into using meshlab (http://www.meshlab.net/) for this kind of thing